# Mysql: Possible errors in queries "WHERE...IN" , "ORDER BY..." and "LIMIT"

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, where-in

As you have observed I have put an ambiguous title for this question, as simply I do not realize (by lack of deep knowledge) if this is the true problem or not.

Let's start then with a short description:

Here is where I select my products:

```
    $select_prod = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id IN ($some_array)";
```

After that here is where I define the pagination stuff:

```
    $query_page = mysql_query($select_prod);
    $product_total = mysql_num_rows($query_page);

            $page_rows = 4;
            $last = ceil($product_total/$page_rows);
            if ($page < 1) { 
               $page = 1; 
            } elseif ($page > $last) {
               $page = $last; 
            }
            $limit = 'limit ' .($page - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
```

And where I prepare the render

```
    $page_query = mysql_query($select_prod . $limit);   
    $results = array();
    while ($array_filter = mysql_fetch_array($page_query)) {
            $results[] = $array_filter;
            }
```

Until this point everything is flowing easily, and I get my products listed as I wanted, BUT in random ORDER.

I have tried to include "ORDER BY price ASC" at the end of the first query like this:

```
    $select_prod = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id IN ($some_array) ORDER BY price ASC";
```

but for a strange reason fails to list the products with the error:

```
    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...
```

I've already had several hours in trying to find where could be the problem, and this forum seems to be the final try for me, after that I would let them order as they want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to print out your full query directly before execution.  Try this instead:

```
$select_prod = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id IN ($some_array) ORDER BY price ASC ";
```

Or, change the `limit` line to have a space before the `limit`.

What I believe the problem is the the lack of space before `limit`.  The snippet `in ()limit 100` is valid SQL.  The snippet `in () order by price asclimit 100` is not valid SQL.

Comment: Well Caught +1 for telling him to print out full query.

Comment: The space before limit, indeeeed. Great observation. So it was all about syntax. Thanks Gordon !